# Postman - change part of return of a POST to localhost

Tags: url, post, return, postman, tweak

I'm making a POST request to a login API in Postman, with body parameters, and it returns like this:

```
{
"redirect_uri": "https://example.com/authorization?etc=etc..."
}
```

I would like Postman to format for me the return to:

```
{
"redirect_uri": "localhost:8080/authorization?etc=etc..."
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What do you want to do with the response, that you cannot change it after the request returns?

Comment: I want to click on the response and open the browser, because I use the API for two purposes, first, I don't replace and get into the real website, second, I replace and get into the development code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it using visualize and the example from Malsha Liyanage:

On tests put this:

```
template = `
<script>
        function copyUrl() {
            let copyText = document.querySelector("#code");
            console.log(copyText)
            copyText.select();    
            document.execCommand("copy");
        }
    </script>
    <div style="margin-left: 50px; margin-top:50px;">
        <p class="block">
            Visit the url
        </p>
        <p class="block">
            <textarea cols="90" id="code">{{response}}</textarea>
        </p>
        <button onclick="copyUrl()">Copy Url</button>
    </div>


`;
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

var url = jsonData.redirect_uri;
url = url.replace("https://example.com","localhost:8080");
// Set visualizer
pm.visualizer.set(template, {
    response: url
});
```

And on Visualize, press button copy to get the url and paste on browser, very simple.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do like:

```
pm.test("response is ok",  ()=>{
    pm.response.to.have.status(200)
})

var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

var url = jsonData.redirect_uri;
url = url.replace("https://example.com","localhost:8080");
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("custom_url", url );
```

Comment: I'm rather new to postman, where would I put that code?

Comment: there is Tests section in the request area. You also need to add a environment variable in postman called custom_url

Comment: it didn't change the redirect_uri response, it just created a new environment variable with the replaced url

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way like to do that. But you can simply use this value in your next request from the saved variable